# MobileFirst and Werable

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I've found a problem during the integration between IBM MobileFirst 7.1 Apps and wearable devices (Android Wear / Samsung Gear) like companion apps.
We are working on IBM MobileFirst 7.1 Hybrid Application that work with wearable watch devices as an Host for Web services integration via adapters invocation.
We implemented an Android Service in Java using native MobileFirst SDK for Android using these class: WL.Connect, WL.Client and WL.invokeProcedure to call Mobile First Adapters.
Below the code used into Android Service used for initializing the client (smartphone host):

```
final WLClient clientC = WLClient.createInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
clientC.connect(new WatchConnectListener(adapterName, procedureName,parameters))
```

The connection was done successfull but the WL.InvokeProcedure raise an error.
Below the error received during the execution:

> Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity

After an investigation we realized that this error is related to the Context passed to the create WLClient.createInstance, the context passed need to be an Activity but in this case the context is an Android Service.

Could somebody suggest how to use WL.Client() into an Android Service for wearable communication ?

Comment: Giuseppe, MobileFirst Platform does not claim supporting Android Wear.

Comment: I understand, however is there any possible suggestion/workaround ? Does MobileFirst 8.x support Android Wear ?

Comment: Official support is available in v8.0 for watchOS 2 and 3. I'll check internally and see if I can find out anything.

Comment: But not Android Wear I guess.... Unfortunately since the Context must be an Activity, it's a showstopping issue calling WLClient.createInstance() within a Service type parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you will make a feature request (RFE) for enhancing the Android SDK with support for running on watches so you could implement such scenarios. Right now this is not supported.

Make the request, here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/ and let your IBM representative know.